# Best data structure for a time line of events derived from an array of data

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

I am trying to store timeline data of events that occurred on a give set of data points. This is best explained by example.

So lets say my input data is an array/list like this:

`input = [1, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 10, 23, 30, 31]` This is 10 days of data

Now say each index in this list represents a day.

Now I want to take this day, and store data that represents 'actions' that this data represents over a give time.

So I will take this input data and for each day, or given days I want to represent what happened. So you'll notice that from input[6:8] there was a sharp increase.

I want to store something like:

`[null, null, null, null, null, null, 'indication sharp increase start (+9)', 'sharp increase continues (+13)', 'sharp increase ends (+7)', null]`

However another thing to consider is that a sharp increase isn't the only thing that could happen. The 'action', in this case 'sharp increase' is also variable.

So what would the best way be to store data like this that would allow it to be easily compared to other array/list of the same structure.

For example if I had a different set of data that outputted:
`[null, 'sharp increase (+19), null, ... etc]`

I want to be able to later determine however similar are 1. The actions and when they happened and 2. How similar are the changes of these actions. Obviously Im not asking how to implement this part, Im just focused on what might be the easiest way to store data to allow the easiest implementation of comparison.

Comment: probably a pandas dataframe

Comment: @DerekEden Thanks Ill look into that!